# How to Trouble Shoot and Fix React.js Checksum Invalid Warning

Tags: node.js, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

I am building an Isomorphic react app using the Isomoprhic React Starter kit project here : https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit

However I am running into a mysterious warning that I have not figured out how to trouble shoot.

React appears to render the code fine in my browser, but apparently there is some problem with rendering on the server.

**Here is the warning that I get:**

> warning.js:45Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container
>   but the checksum was invalid. This generally means that you are using
>   server rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what
>   the client was expecting. React injected new markup to compensate
>   which works but you have lost many of the benefits of server
>   rendering. Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is
>   different on the client or server:

**and Here is the code from my component that is the source of the problem:**

```
class TestPage extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = { n: 0 }
  }

  static contextTypes = {
    onSetTitle: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    blahblah: 'blah'
  }

  render() {
    let title = 'Test Page';
    this.context.onSetTitle(title);
    return (
      <div className="page">
        <div className="pageContainer">
          <h1>{title}</h1>
            {this.state.n}
          <TestComponent blahblah={this.props.blahblah} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```